# Codnameone:how to stop timer after pressing home button in android app

Tags: codenameone

I want to stop timer when I pressed home button in android app.
which event occurs when I press home button?
how to stop timer when press home button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main class you have `init`, `start`, `stop` & `destroy`.

`stop` is invoked when the app is suspended. `start` will be invoked again when you return to the app.

Comment: I have statemachine class which is extended from statemachinebase class but there is no start and stop method.There is only init method.so where do I get start and stop methods?

Comment: Those methods are in the main class, not in StateMachine.

Comment: Are you looking in your main package, com.companyname.appname or however you named it? The main class won't be in the UserClasses package.

Comment: other than statemachine class we have only statemachinebase class in generated package in this class we have startapp method only there is no stop method in this class

Comment: Did you create a Codename One project? Every Codename One project has a main class whose name/package you type in when you create the new project